# Hyperlink to open latest item in a folder (SharePoint 2010)

Tags: hyperlink

I'm trying to insert a link on the home page. The link will be to a folder in a document library on a different page (but within the same site) and will open up the latest file added to that folder.

Answer (score 3):

On the document library create a view sorted descending on the column which you want to use in your definition of latest item (Id, Modified, Created, ...) with a limit of 1 item and just showing the column "Title (linked to item)"

Insert a List View Web Part using that view on the page.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Per but what I'm trying to achieve is to create a link on the home page that opens up the most recent document added in a folder in document library.

Comment: And what I describe will do that. If it doesn't fit your requirements then you should add those requirements to your question as well as more information about which toolset you're allowed to use.

Comment: Hi Per, I have edited my original question. Please see if you can help me with this.